# Ansible inventory for environment variables within a role

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-role

I got an Ansible role that Im wanting to execute a psql script with. The name of the role is "db_scripts" and I will list the contents of respective directories/files below.

**db_scripts/tasks/mail.yml**

```
-
  name: "Run the SQLS"
  command: "psql -f \"{{ script }}\"/files/my_sql_script.sql"
  environment:
    PGDATABASE: "{{ db_name }}"
    PGUSER: "{{ db_user }}"
    PGHOST: "{{ db_host }}"
    PGPORT: "{{ db_port }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
```

**db_scripts/files/my_sql_script.yml**

```
insert into employees(name, contact) values (Jack, 5555555);
```

**db_scripts/default/main.yml**

```
script: "{{ role_path }}"
```

**/app/production/inventory**

```
[dbservers]
db_host=192.168.1.100 db_name=mycompany db_user=abc db_port=3308
```

**/app/playbooks/run_sqls.yml**

```
- name: Run sql
  hosts: dbservers
  roles:
    - db_scripts
```

I run the playbook "run_sqls" as follows.

```
ansible-playbook run_sqls.yml -i inventories/app/production/inventory
```

What I want to understand is that how I should specify the values for following environment vars so that they can be dynamic and can be used by the hosts of other environments i.e: development etc..

```
PGDATABASE: "{{ db_name }}"
PGUSER: "{{ db_user }}"
PGHOST: "{{ db_host }}"
PGPORT: "{{ db_port }}"
```

Specifying them in respective inventory file doesn't seem to work,playbook errors out for "undefined vars" which make sense. Following is how I've attempted. 
**/app/production/inventory**

```
[dbservers]
192.168.1.100 db_name=mycompany db_user=abc db_port=3308
```

**The error when the playbook is run**

```
TASK [db_scripts : Run the SQLS] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The field 'environment' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: 'db_host' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/db_scripts/tasks/mail.yml': line 37, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n-\n  name: \"Run the SQLS\"\n  ^ here\n"}
```

Please note when the values for the said env vars are specified under "db_scripts/default/main.yml" 
,playbook Runs perfectly. Really appreciate some inputs. I've just started with ansible so please be as simple as you can be with examples. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You said: `"... playbook errors out for "undefined vars" which make sense."` Would it be possible to explain what exactly makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
[dbservers]
192.168.1.100 db_name=mycompany db_user=abc db_port=3308
```

> Q: *"Specifying them (vars) in respective inventory file doesn't seem to work, playbook errors out for "undefined vars" which make sense.*"

A: The variables from this inventory should work as expected. Simply test it

```
- hosts: dbservers
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg:
          - '{{ db_name }}'
          - '{{ db_user }}'
          - '{{ db_host }}'
          - '{{ db_port }}'
```

**There are 2 problems**

1) `db_host` is missing in the inventory

2) The path in command `inventories/app/production/inventory` is different from the path described `/app/production/inventory`

```
ansible-playbook run_sqls.yml -i inventories/app/production/inventory
```

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir Yeah db_host from the inventory was missed out in error when posting the question. However there is still no luck. I've updated my origingal question with the playbook error.